# Comparing two columns in Laravel 5

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am using Laravel

Let's say, I have two date fields in my table. If I want to compare them, i can do whereRaw clause.

```
$query->whereRaw('date1 > date2')->get()
```

Is there a way to make a modification to date2 inside this query, so it is actually date2-1day?

Something like:

```
$query->whereRaw('date1 > (date2-1day)')->get()
```

Answer (score 3):

You are free to call any SQL code in the "raw" part of your query, so you could do sth like below:

```
$query->whereRaw('date1 > DATE_SUB(date2, INTERVAL 1 DAY)')->get();
```

Keep in mind that executing SQL code this way will make your queries work only in databases that support such functions.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be using `whereColumn` like

```
$users = DB::table('users')
             ->whereColumn('updated_at', '>', 'created_at')
             ->get();
```

OR

```
UserTable::whereRaw('column1 != column2')->get();
```